# MessageBox.Show not working

Tags: c#, messagebox

This is my code: (It's a dynamic link library)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DLL
{
    public class Main
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hello");
    }
}
```

However, Visual Studio gives me the following error:

*"The name MessageBox.Show does not exist in the current context."*
Does anybody see a problem with my code? I've added references to System.Windows.Forms. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't, if you are in a console application you could use Console.WriteLine(). Otherwise, if you are in a dll, you could just add something in the EventLog.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to display MessageBox on a Console Application.

Create a windows Form Application and,

```
public Form1()
{
 InitializeComponent();
 MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

Comment: So I can't do this within a DLL?